# Change image in value on dropdown using Bootstrap 4

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I would like to change the value of the image as and when the dropdown value changes too and not just the text. How do I go about this?

HTML

```
<div class="input-group">
    <div class="input-group-btn">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
            <img src="https://i.postimg.cc/44bmkyGL/sdgs-1.jpg"> One
        </button>
        <div class="dropdown-menu">
            <a class="dropdown-item sectionScroll" href="#one"><img src="https://i.postimg.cc/44bmkyGL/sdgs-1.jpg"> One</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item sectionScroll" href="#two"> <img src="https://i.postimg.cc/4NWyy0mp/sdgs-2.jpg"> Two</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item sectionScroll" href="#three"> <img src="https://i.postimg.cc/dVD1y9yp/sdgs-3.jpg"> Three</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item sectionScroll" href="#three"> <img src="https://i.postimg.cc/pdFL0XkB/sdgs-4.jpg"> Four</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item sectionScroll" href="#three"> <img src="https://i.postimg.cc/85gPxQ0g/sdgs-5.jpg"> Five</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$(".dropdown-menu a ").click(function(){
  $(this).parents(".input-group-btn").find('.btn').text($(this).text    ());
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this using `closest()` method to find the correct element.

```js
$(".dropdown-menu a ").click(function() {
  $image = $(this).find('img').attr("src")
  $(this).closest('.input-group-btn').find('button img').attr("src", $image);
  $(this).closest('.input-group-btn').find('button span').text($(this).text());
});
```

```css
img {
  width: 24px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-xrRywqdh3PHs8keKZN+8zzc5TX0GRTLCcmivcbNJWm2rs5C8PRhcEn3czEjhAO9o" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="input-group">
  <div class="input-group-btn">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
            <img src="https://i.postimg.cc/44bmkyGL/sdgs-1.jpg"> <span>One</span>
        </button>
    <div class="dropdown-menu">
      <a class="dropdown-item sectionScroll" href="#one"><img src="https://i.postimg.cc/44bmkyGL/sdgs-1.jpg"> One</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item sectionScroll" href="#two"> <img src="https://i.postimg.cc/4NWyy0mp/sdgs-2.jpg"> Two</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item sectionScroll" href="#three"> <img src="https://i.postimg.cc/dVD1y9yp/sdgs-3.jpg"> Three</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item sectionScroll" href="#three"> <img src="https://i.postimg.cc/pdFL0XkB/sdgs-4.jpg"> Four</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item sectionScroll" href="#three"> <img src="https://i.postimg.cc/85gPxQ0g/sdgs-5.jpg"> Five</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You may try this:

```
 $(".dropdown-menu a ").click(function(){
  $image=$(this).children('img').attr("src")
  $(this).parents(".input-group-btn").find('.btn').children('img').attr("src",$image);
```

$(this).parents(".input-group-btn").find('.btn').text($(this).text());
      });

Comment: Thanks but I tried and it's not working: https://jsfiddle.net/h7nyocf6/

Comment: I have edited the answer and checked it in the fiddle seems to be working fine you need to code for text change

Comment: The text stops to work. Anyways, I have accepted the answer from another user. Thank you os much.